# How to monitor a nodejs worker with sentry?

Tags: node.js, sentry

I have a node js app (actually a worker) that i need to monitor. However, I am not sure how to integrate sentry on it.

```
const Sentry = require("@sentry/node");
const Tracing = require("@sentry/tracing");

Sentry.init({
  dsn: process.env.my_dsn,
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});

function start(){

    
    (async function () {
      // job
    })();
    
    // what is the best way to integrate sentry ?
 }
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it that you want to do? What you have there will already give you the basics -- e.g. error handling. If you want tracing as well then you need to decide what exactly you want to trace and set up monitoring around the transactions. Your question is open-ended enough that it's hard to give you much practical advice.

see https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/tracing/distributed-tracing/